# как на jquery с помощью ajax динамически обновить форму данного вида?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

```
<div id="target" class="col-xs-5">
<label>ФИО</label>
<input class="formcontrol" name="number" value="<?php echo $sitedata['name']">
</div>
```

Comment: Не очень понятен вопрос, что именно вы хотите здесь обновить и при каком действии?

Comment: У меня есть id target структура которого должна остаться неизменной, просто в value должны появиться данные из массива. Пока у меня получается только уничтожить весь div и вместо него вставить данные, что совсем не то что мне нужно =(

Comment: Ну и где код который что-то делает с этим дивом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы обновить `value` в `input` нужно выбрать его правильным селектором
`$('#target input').val("ваше значение");`
Можно добавить выбор по имени input
`$('#target input[name="number"]').val("ваше значение");`

В вашем коде видно что у `input` не хватает атрибута `type`, и видимо вы используете Bootstrap - класс должен быть не `formcontrol`, а `form-control`

Comment: Дело в селекторе, спасибо за пример #target input[name="number"]